# ColumnTransformer is adding new empty Records (with NaN) to the original X_train subset

Tags: python, dataframe, function, data-preprocessing

I have to say that I have used the following code for preprocessing data on the exactly the same dataset I am trying to use now for the past weeks with no issues. Today something has changed and I cannot pinpoint the issue.

```
##      0. IMPORT MODULES AND FUNCTIONS
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTENC # This needs installation of the imbalanced-learn package
from imblearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE # RFE is for Recursive Feature Elimination
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV # Recursive Feature Elimination with Cross Validation
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate, KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedStratifiedKFold
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
from xgboost import XGBClassifier

import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.getcwd() + "/helperfunctions")
from preprocfunc import OutlierTrans,  MakeOrdinal, ReplaceVals
```

And  this is the contento of preprocfunc.py

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin


class OutlierTrans(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
  def __init__(self, threshold=1.5):
    self.threshold = threshold

  def fit(self, X, y=None):
    return self

  def transform(self, X, y=None):
    Xnew = X.copy()
    for col in Xnew.columns:
      thirdq, firstq = Xnew[col].quantile(0.75), \
                       Xnew[col].quantile(0.25)
      interquartilerange = self.threshold * (thirdq - firstq)
      outlierhigh, outlierlow = interquartilerange + thirdq, \
                                firstq - interquartilerange
      Xnew.loc[(Xnew[col] > outlierhigh) | \
               (Xnew[col] < outlierlow), col] = np.nan
    return Xnew.values

# -----------------------------------------------------------------

class MakeOrdinal(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
  def fit(self, X, y=None):
    return self

  def transform(self, X, y=None):
    Xnew = X.copy()
    for col in Xnew.columns:
      cats = np.sort(Xnew[col].unique())
      Xnew[col] = Xnew. \
        apply(lambda x: int(np.where(cats == \
                                     x[col])[0]), axis=1)
    return Xnew.values

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
class ReplaceVals(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
  def __init__(self, repdict):
    self.repdict = repdict

  def fit(self, X, y=None):
    return self

  def transform(self, X, y=None):
    Xnew = X.copy().replace(self.repdict)
    return Xnew.values
```

These functions have been totally fine in the recent past

Now I go to the Import and pre-processing stage

```
##  1. IMPORT The Dataset
df = pd.read_excel("_Datasets\\DOCS_GlucoseMeas479Pts_29Mar23.xlsx")

## DATAFRAME INSPECTION
df.head(5).T # first 5 rows
print(f"{b_}DOCS Database (Observations, Variables):{r_}{df.shape}\n")
print(f"{y_}Data types of data columns: \n{m_}{df.dtypes}")
df.info()

# DEFINE VECTORS OF PREDICTORS
num_cols = [
               "lab_gluctests",
               "lab_hbpre",
               "tm_glcabrng"
                                ]

for var in num_cols:
    df[var] = df[var].astype('float64')

binary_cols = [
                "hx_infendo",
                "rf_dialysis"
                                ]

for var in binary_cols:
    df[var] = df[var].astype('Int64') # Convert from Category to Float (otherwise the merging does not work)

cat_cols = [
            "admreasnb",
            "op_urgent",
            "tx_diabmeds"
                            ]

for var in  cat_cols:
    df[var] = df[var].astype('Int64') # Convert from Category to Float (otherwise the merging does not work)

ordin_cols = [
                    "op_redo"
                                     ] # Ordinal Variables to be encoded

for var in ordin_cols:
    df[var] = df[var].astype('Int64') # Convert from Category to Float (otherwise the merging does not work)

Outcomes =  [
                "out_inf",
                "out_swi",
                "out_readm",
                "out_death"
                            ]

for var in Outcomes:
    df[var] = df[var].astype('Int64') # Convert from Category to Float (otherwise the merging does not work)

target = df[['out_inf']]

# Define a Dataframe for al predictors/features
features = df[num_cols + binary_cols + cat_cols + ordin_cols]

# Split the dataset in train/test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, target, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
```

So far so good

```
##  APPLY COLUMN TRANSFORMATION
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ohe = OneHotEncoder(drop='first', handle_unknown = "ignore", sparse_output=False)

standtrans = make_pipeline(OutlierTrans(3),
  SimpleImputer(strategy="mean"),
  StandardScaler())
ordintrans = make_pipeline(MakeOrdinal(),
  StandardScaler())
bintrans = make_pipeline(ohe)
cattrans = make_pipeline(ohe)

coltrans = ColumnTransformer(
  transformers=[
    ("stand", standtrans, num_cols),
    ("ord", ordintrans, ordin_cols),
    ("bin", bintrans, binary_cols),
    ("cat", cattrans, cat_cols),
  ]
)
```

Now, in order to debug and before proceeding to the next step (run the analysis)

```
X_train.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 383 entries, 374 to 172
Data columns (total 9 columns):
 #   Column         Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------         --------------  -----  
 0   lab_gluctests  383 non-null    float64
 1   lab_hbpre      383 non-null    float64
 2   tm_glcabrng    383 non-null    float64
 3   hx_infendo     383 non-null    Int64  
 4   rf_dialysis    383 non-null    Int64  
 5   admreasnb      383 non-null    Int64  
 6   op_urgent      383 non-null    Int64  
 7   tx_diabmeds    383 non-null    Int64  
 8   op_redo        383 non-null    Int64  


# Fit the ColumnTransformer to X_train
coltrans.fit(X_train)

# Transform the features in X_train
X_train_transformed = coltrans.transform(X_train)
```

This is completed with no erros BUT

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 457 entries, 0 to 396
Data columns (total 20 columns):
 #   Column                Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                --------------  -----  
 0   stand__x0             383 non-null    float64
 1   stand__x1             383 non-null    float64
 2   stand__x2             383 non-null    float64
 3   ord__x0               383 non-null    float64
 4   bin__hx_infendo_1.0   383 non-null    float64
 5   bin__rf_dialysis_1.0  383 non-null    float64
 6   cat__admreasnb_1.0    383 non-null    float64
 7   cat__admreasnb_2.0    383 non-null    float64
 8   cat__admreasnb_3.0    383 non-null    float64
 9   cat__admreasnb_4.0    383 non-null    float64
 10  cat__admreasnb_5.0    383 non-null    float64
 11  cat__admreasnb_6.0    383 non-null    float64
 12  cat__admreasnb_7.0    383 non-null    float64
 13  cat__admreasnb_8.0    383 non-null    float64
 14  cat__op_urgent_1.0    383 non-null    float64
 15  cat__op_urgent_2.0    383 non-null    float64
 16  cat__tx_diabmeds_1.0  383 non-null    float64
 17  cat__tx_diabmeds_2.0  383 non-null    float64
 18  cat__tx_diabmeds_3.0  383 non-null    float64
 19  cat__tx_diabmeds_4.0  383 non-null    float64
dtypes: float64(20)
memory usage: 75.0 KB
```

We now have 457 records in plaace of the expected 383
and in facts the 74 added records are empty

```
X_train_transformed.isnull().sum()

Out[95]: 
stand__x0               74
stand__x1               74
stand__x2               74
ord__x0                 74
bin__hx_infendo_1.0     74
bin__rf_dialysis_1.0    74
cat__admreasnb_1.0      74
cat__admreasnb_2.0      74
cat__admreasnb_3.0      74
cat__admreasnb_4.0      74
cat__admreasnb_5.0      74
cat__admreasnb_6.0      74
cat__admreasnb_7.0      74
cat__admreasnb_8.0      74
cat__op_urgent_1.0      74
cat__op_urgent_2.0      74
cat__tx_diabmeds_1.0    74
cat__tx_diabmeds_2.0    74
cat__tx_diabmeds_3.0    74
cat__tx_diabmeds_4.0    74
```

Could anyone please help ? I am stuck and going crazy...

I do not understand why and how the Custom Transformers (OutLiersTrans and MakeOrdinal) add empty records and How to prevent this

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts, I have finally got what was going on: Few days ago, following advices from a book, I have decied to make effective the following general setting for sklearn

> sklearn.set_config(transform_output="pandas")

This is apparently nice since force sklearn to output everything as a Pandas dqataframe in place of the default numpy array, BUT it also screwed all my pre-processing pipeline. So DO NOT use it and deal with numpy arrays when working in sklearn !